# jquery custom plugin doesn't go in each statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

Here is my custom jquery plugin i have created. I am using RequireJs to load this plugin, but for some reason it doesn't recongize the following statement:

```
return this.each(function () {
     console.log('b');
});
```

Is there a reason why this would be called?

Here is complete plugin:

```
(function (factory) {
        if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
            // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
            define(['jquery'], factory);
        } else {
            // Browser globals
            factory(jQuery);
        }
    }(function($) {
        var methods = {
            init: function (options) {
                console.log('a');
                return this.each(function () {
                    console.log('b');
                    var $element = $(this), // reference to the jQuery version of the current DOM element
                     element = this;      // reference to the actual DOM element
                    $(this).delegate("li > a", "click", function () {
                        console.log('click');
                        // Figure out current list via CSS class
                        var curList = $element.find("a.current").attr("href").substring(1)

                        // List moving to
                        $newList = $(this),

                        // Figure out ID of new list
                        listID = $newList.attr("href").substring(1),

                        // Set outer wrapper height to (static) height of current inner list
                        $allListWrap = $element.find(".tabCont"),
                        curListHeight = $allListWrap.height();
                        $allListWrap.height(curListHeight);

                        if ((listID != curList) && ($element.find(":animated").length == 0)) {

                            // Fade out current list
                            $element.find("#" + curList).fadeOut(base.options.speed, function () {

                                // Fade in new list on callback
                                $element.find("#" + listID).fadeIn(base.options.speed);

                                // Adjust outer wrapper to fit new list snuggly
                                var newHeight = $element.find("#" + listID).height();
                                $allListWrap.animate({
                                    height: newHeight
                                }, function () {
                                    $('.tabCont').css('height', 'auto');

                                });

                                // Remove highlighting - Add to just-clicked tab
                                $element.find(".tabsNav li a").removeClass("current");
                                $newList.addClass("current");

                            });

                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            }
        };

        $.fn.flazingoTabs = function (method) {
            if (methods[method]) { return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); }
            else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) { return methods.init.apply(this, arguments); }
            else { $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on flazingo tabs"); }
        }
    }));
```

Loading plugin (main.clients):

```
define(['ko', 'mapping', 'flazingotabs', 'spinner'],
    function (ko, mapping, tabs, spinner) {
    var
        initTabs = function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#tabs").flazingoTabs('init');
            });
        },
        run = function () {
            spinner.start();
            spinner.goByeBye();
            initTabs();
            });
        };
    return {
        run: run
    };
});
```

This is the load (app.clients.js):

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "../Scripts/app/views/administrator/clients",
    "paths": {
        "app.clients": "app.clients",
        "main.clients": "main.clients",
        "jquery": "//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min",
        "spinner": "../../../helpers/spinner",
        "ko": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min",
        "knockout.postbox": "../../../../lib/knockout-postbox",
        "knockout.validation": "../../../../lib/knockout.validation",
        'knockout.bindings': "../../../../lib/knockout.bindings",
        "mapping": "../../../../lib/knockout.mapping-latest.debug",        
        "toastr": "../../../../lib/toastr",
        "flazingotabs": "../../../../lib/flazingotabs"        },
    shim: {
        "knockout.validation": ["ko"],
        "mapping": ["ko"],
        "flazingotabs" : ["jquery"]
    }
});
require(["ko"], function (ko) {
    //manually set the global ko property
    window.ko = ko;

    //then bring in knockout validation
    require(["knockout.validation"], function () {
        ko.validation.configure({
            insertMessages: false,
            decorateElement: true,
            errorElementClass: 'error'
        });
        // Load the main app module to start the app
        require(["main.clients"], function (bs) { bs.run(); });
    });
});
```

Comment: Working fine : http://jsfiddle.net/xeP3H/. Are you sure you call `$('selector').flazingoTabs('init')` in a DOM ready?

Comment: Yes, its only printing 'a', and not running the code console.log('b');

Comment: Added more info as far as how I load it

Comment: If you do a console log of `$("#tabs")` in the DOM ready handler, doesnt it has selected something?

Comment: [context: document, selector: "#tabs", jquery: "2.1.0", constructor: function, toArray: function…]
context: document
selector: "#tabs"
__proto__: Object[0]

Comment: You see, that's the problem, `$("#tabs")` return nothing, it is not there yet when you call your plugin.

Comment: I see! You are right. I implement the domReady module with RequireJS and that sees to work now. Its not was not loading at the right place.